# Trace on Chrome/Browser console

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Does anybody know how to trace messages in the google chrome console using Flex3. In the logs section for example.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "YourString");
```

[See here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=19_External_Interface_04.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks work perfect. I also installed Vizzy from http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/downloads/list which worked great. console.clear is not working well though any idea? Thanks again

Comment: Did you try `console.clear()` ? It works for me. Also here's another tool I've used called [Alcon](http://www.tetragonengine.com/alcon/). And you can find a few more tools listed [here](http://ntt.cc/2008/03/29/the-list-of-helpful-flex-or-flash-debug-tools.html). Also if this answer is satisfactory, please mark as the correct answer.